# Space between image and border

Tags: html, css, border, space

Why is there a space? How can I fix that? Please help me.

[image]

```
<div class="person-Description">
                    <img src="Person.png" alt="Danielle Harris">
                    <h1>Danielle Harris</h1>
                    <h3>Software Technician</h3>
                </div>
```

```
.person-Description{
            display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column;
            width: 100%; align-self: flex-start; text-align: center;
            align-items: center; justify-content: center;
        }
        .person-Description img{
            display: block; width: 60%; user-select: none;
            border-radius: 30px; border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
        }
```

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by space between image and border. Your image style does add a white 5px border.     border-radius: 30px; border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean the small space between the image itself and the border, which can hardly be seen. To fix this issue, you have to add a background color to the image. The background color should be the same color as your border. This way, the little space will disappear visually. So in your case, simply add `background: #ffffff;` to your CSS rule `.person-Description img`.

```css
.person-Description{
  display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%; align-self: flex-start; text-align: center;
  align-items: center; justify-content: center;
}
.person-Description img{
  display: block; width: 60%; user-select: none;
  border-radius: 30px; border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="person-Description">
  <img src="Person.png" alt="Danielle Harris">
  <h1>Danielle Harris</h1>
  <h3>Software Technician</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the white border in .person-Description img style

```
 .person-Description img{style
       display: block; width: 60%; user-select: none;  
  }
```