# why there is a white space around image and it's border when the border is greater than 1px?

Tags: html, css, sass, border

when i adding border width greater than 1px white space is creating around image
here
https://front-end-mentor-works.github.io/e-com-product-page/

these images (below the main product image )in the boxes are not completely filled to those boxes .

i want to acheive ( the original design )

https://github.com/front-end-mentor-works/e-com-product-page/blob/main/design/desktop-design.jpg

i checked in developer console there is no margin and padding.

and i tried solution like setting font size: 0 , and making background similar to border color

1. font-size:0
2. making background simlilar to border color
3. display:block
   4.vertical align:top

i have hosted my code on github pages

https://front-end-mentor-works.github.io/e-com-product-page/

repo link
https://github.com/front-end-mentor-works/e-com-product-page

How to remove this white space around image?

i have tried the solutions of this question
similar question [Space between image and border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998952/space-between-image-and-border)
and other similar questions none of them is not removing the white space?

my code is

`

```
.product-thumbnail-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  gap: 6%;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.product-thumbnail {
  width: 20.6%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  &-active {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid $Orange;
    background: $Orange;
    filter: opacity(0.3);
  }
}


  [1]: https://front-end-mentor-works.github.io/e-com-product-page/
```

Comment: wrap the image in a div tag and apply border and border-radius to this wrapping div element

Comment: thanks but it didn't solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything with the `background-size` property?

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.php

If you haven't, I'd start with that and see what you can come up with.

Comment: no i have not tried ,so i need to remove img tags and add these image as background image , ok i will try this solution

Comment: it worked
i set background size to cover
for that i had to mention both height and width seperately for the thumbnail boxes

Comment: for selectinn active thumbnail iam using filter:opacity(0.5) but when iam looking too closely iam feeling that my desing is matching with original design.

do you know how to add white layer above this image

Comment: @sinan It depends on where you want the white layer. If you want it within the box/div then you'd probably want to add something like `padding-top: 1px;` to your CSS.